# HashMap returning null even though hashCode/equals are overriden

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap that maps a custom object `TokenDocumentPair` to a `Double`. The `TokenDocumentPair` is as follows:

```
  static class TokenDocumentPair {
    int documentNum;
    String token;
    public TokenDocumentPair(String token, int documentNum) {
      this.token = token;
      this.documentNum = documentNum;
    }

    public boolean equals(TokenDocumentPair other) {
      return (this.documentNum == other.documentNum && this.token.equals(other.token));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
      int result = 1;
      result = 37 * result + Objects.hashCode(this.documentNum);
      result = 37 * result + Objects.hashCode(this.token);
      return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return String.format("[Document #%s, Token: %s]", documentNum, token);
    }
  }
```

The problem is, when I create `TokenDocumentPair pair1 = new TokenDocumentPair("hello", 1)` , store it into a `HashMap<TokenDocumentPair, Double> map`, and try to fetch it with `TokenDocumentPair pair2 = new TokenDocumentPair("hello", 1)`, it returns `null`. However, I was under the impression that since my hashcode and equals method match up and are based on the two fields stored, the hash map would be able to find the original `pair1` and return its value to me.

```
TokenDocumentPair pair1 = new TokenDocumentPair("hello", 1);
TokenDocumentPair pair2 = new TokenDocumentPair("hello", 1);
assert pair1.hashCode() == pair2.hashCode(); // ok
assert pair1.equals(pair2); // ok

HashMap<TokenDocumentPair, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(pair1, 0.0);
map.get(pair2); // null
map.containsKey(pair2); // false
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`equals` method is not overridden. You have overloaded it.

Signature of method [`Object#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) to override must look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    //...
}
```

In order to make sure you're overriding a method, use `@Override` annotation when declaring the method. If you add this annotation to your current `equals` method, you will get a compiler error and a proper error message.